# Yet another "attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Tags: python, package, importerror

Yes, this is another question about *that* error.  I've looked through several of the questions but none of them I examined seemed relevant to my situation.

My project looks like

```
├── setup.py
├── src
│   ├── c_implementation.py
│   ├── implementation.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── kwchecker.py
```

and my setup.py contains

```py
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    py_modules=["kwchecker"],
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    ...
)
```

kwchecker.py has, near the top,

```py
from . import implementation
from . import c_implementation
```

When I build my package and pip install it, however, I get the infamous error when I try to `import kwchecker`.  Specifically, it's on the line `from . import implementation`.

Why would this be?  I'm not pulling from some other folder in my directory structure.

Comment: My first guess is to just do `import .implementation`?

Comment: "invalid syntax"

Comment: @napuzba, so, what's the answer?  I can't import things this way because I didn't run Python with the -m option?  I'm not even running `kwchecker` directly so I don't understand why the `__main__`/`__package__` thing is even an issue.